# Inline-block elements have different vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to get a link with an icon after a link.

For example:

```
Link [icon]
```

The line height I'd like is 30px. So, I have such a markup:

```
<div class="phone-support">
   <a href="#">We'll call you</a><i class="icon"></i>
</div>

.phone-support a {
   display       : inline-block;
   line-height   : 30px;
   padding-right : 5px;
   height        : 30px;
}

.phone-support i.icon {
   display       : inline-block;
   height        : 30px;
   width         : 30px;
   background    : url('/path/to/sprite.png') -10px -10px;
}
```

I considered it should work, but the height of `.phone-support` becomes 41px, but why? And elements aren't aligned vertically. They simple stays each after each, why this happens?

P.S. My browser is Chromium 18. Don't pay attention on that there is no ie-inline-block-fix, etc. CSS code is simplified just to point to the problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting i.icon's height by throwing a padding-top definition to offset the sprite image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/adugoz/1/edit)*

Just put your `<i>` inside the `<a>`. The benefit? your image will be linkable.

```
<div class="phone-support">
   <a href="#">We'll call you  <i class="icon"></i> </a>
</div>
```

Than set a `vertical-align:top;` to set your image at the top of the `<a>` parent.

```
.phone-support i.icon {
     display       : inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
     height        : 30px;
     width         : 30px;
     background    : url(your url here);
     margin-left   : 10px;  /*add some space*/
}
```

Comment: I've forgot, that icon should be clickable too, so I really need to put `<i>` inside the `<a>`. Thank you, I've made this way. Problem is only that, space between text and icon I made with `&nbsp`. But it's ok. I do not need exact pixels ;)

Comment: You don't need to use `&nbsp` : just set a left-margin! http://jsbin.com/adugoz/2/edit

Comment: P.S: I would not use line-height cause it won't show up well in some mobile browsers. To fix that I use align:middle and instead of line-height i just play with padding. http://jsbin.com/adugoz/3/edit

Comment: Oh, yeap. It works with margin. I'm almost sleeping, so that's why I'm asking simple questions and nopping ;)

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the CSS "vertical-align" property.  For most elements, it defaults to "baseline", which is probably the only thing you don't want.  I tend to favor "vertical-align: middle".

What happens with "vertical-align: baseline" is inline-block elements get a gap beneath them of about the size of the hanging part of the letter "g", which is probably the extra 3 pixels of height you're seeing.

Comment: If you want the tops of the elements to line up with each other even if they're different sizes, then your options are "top" and "text-top".

Comment: vertical-align : middle fixed the problem. Thanks. But what height becomes more than 30, I can't understand. It's not because of letters such as `g`, `y`, etc...

Comment: The height of the line of text (that the a element is contained within, since it's part of the inline flow) becomes more than 30.  A line of text always leaves space below the baseline, even if there are no actual hanging characters using that space.  (When dealing with actual text in paragraph form, it's pretty obvious why that's necessary: the rare line with no hanging characters on it would stand out weirdly otherwise.)